# Strings as comments -- what's the performance hit?

Tags: javascript, performance, comments

I'm developing a module loading script that goes through JS files line-by-line and scans for certain statements (*e.g. require(file.js)*).

I am currently declaring these statements as **comments** to avoid the browser from reporting errors, like so:

```js
// require(file.js)
```

But I was wondering if I maybe could write them as "floating" strings without a variable, like this:

```js
"require(file.js)";
```

This would make it easier to identify these statements and their executional effect, instead of having them as comments that can easily be dismissed (and subconsciously thought to skip execution).

But I have some concerns I would like to be addressed:

- **What is the performance hit of having floating strings?**

  - Would they take up memory? or would they be GC'ed immediately?
  - Would they be parsed? (would the interpreter go through each character?)
- Are there any pitfalls for using floating values?

Comment: This is implementation-dependent, but it's hard to imagine any JS compiler producing code for them. They'll just take up memory in the source code that's retained in the function object.

Comment: There are some languages where putting strings at the beginning of the function is the defined way to attach a documentation comment that's retained at runtime. Python and Common Lisp use this convention.

Comment: @Barmar: thanks for your input! By taking up memory, do you mean that the string will be kept in RAM during the execution of a function? What if the floating string is declared in the global scope, would that mean taking up RAM throughout the entirety of the script's execution? Or are you simply referring to the fact that the compiler will skip comments inherently, but will keep floating strings somewhere (what is function object)? Thanks :)

Comment: The source code of every function is kept in memory, you can see it if you call `func.toString()`. The string will be in that source code, that's all I mean.

Comment: @Barmar: you are right :O! I just checked in Chrome's JS console, and it also retains any comments declared :/ Thanks for fast reply, btw ⭐